# How to display Vue component inside Storybook

Tags: javascript, vue.js, storybook

So I'm sort of confused to how Storybook works with Vue (I've previously used it with React and have managed to get it working).

So far, I have installed it correctly. For example, I have a `1-Button.stories.js` file which looks like this:

```
import Button from '../src/components/Test';

export default {
  title: 'Button',
};

export const text = () => ({
  components: { Button },
  template: '<button-counter></button-counter>',
});
```

Now this renders to Storybook, but it only renders the template. How do I get it to render the component, i.e `Button`?

Here's what my `Button` looks like from `Test.vue`:

```
// Define a new component called button-counter
export const Button = Vue.component('button-counter', {
  data: function () {
    return {
      count: 0
    }
  },
  template: '<button v-bind:style="{ color: activeColor, fontSize: fontSize + 'px' }" v-on:click="count++">You clicked me {{ count }} times.</button>'
})
```

The way I would expect it to work is that `<button-counter>` would have the inline styles applied to it, but it doesn't.

What am I getting wrong here?

I don't think this is relevant but just incase, here's how my folder structure looks:

[image]